# Where do R2-D2's drinks come from?

Tags: star-wars, droids, food

This image from the [*Star Wars Blueprints:  The Ultimate Collection*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756638690) shows R2's drink serving arm, labeled #5.

[image]

However, it doesn't explain where the beverage reservoirs are located.  The only fluids mentioned in the schematic are hydraulic fluid and lubricant, and I doubt that Jabba wanted R2 to poison his guests with either of those substances.

### So where does the booze come from?

Comment: A TV comes with the ability to watch TV channels but the channels aren't watchable if you don't have cable, or whatever. :)

Comment: This isn't Vape we're talking about Artoo can't shoot beer on command

Comment: The real question is, where did he get the cup of tea?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: From the drink dispenser in the galley, after he acquired the necessary components to program it away from Advanced Tea Substitute.  (I vaguely recall that the component might have been on the planet Traal?)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Not from R2-D2?

This is a modification so R2-D2 can serve drinks on Jabba's sail barge, but he's only serving them, not producing or dispensing them.  Presumably they come from some bartender or a dispensing system of some kind.

[image]

As you can see, a customized tray has been fitted onto his hips and there's no obvious way the glasses could be dispensed from within his body, so dispensing the liquid too wouldn't be much of a timesaver.

## From R2-D2?

**However**, some images, like this
[image]

and this Deluxe One-Sixth Scale Figure

do seem to clearly have tubes, which we can only assume means they are for dispensing liquid from within a reservoir in R2-D2.   The image in OP does contain **#14 Cargo Compartment** as well as any number of other useless subsystems which could have been removed to make space for a reservoir (and cooling system?) as R2-D2 was no longer serving his primary function of Astromech.

This is not demonstrated directly, so we can really only say it's **inconclusive**.

Comment: @N_Soong, why can't you?

Comment: Indeed he has them balanced on a small table like object that C3PO knocks off, one assumes another droid puts drinks on that then he goes and serves them - would make sense

Comment: Canon source???

Comment: You can see it in [this screenshot from the movie](http://www.jedidefender.com/spearson/r2tender.jpg).

Comment: How sad that he went from fixing spaceships in battle to working as a waiter.

Comment: So basically, R2-D2 gets his drinks from a pop machine? ;-)

Comment: @N_Soong I upvoted for you.

Comment: I always thought it was an attachment of some variety.  Perhaps after-market.

Comment: I've revised the answer, because I believe the evidence is inconclusive and there is some evidence he may have a dispensing capability.

Comment: The tubes on the toy could just be power/hydraulics to drive the little grabber on the end.  (Or they could be that the sculptor thought "I'll put pipes on the arm, industrial stuff has pipes....")

Comment: The tube appears to be filled with a clear liquid (hydraulic fluid?) whereas the drinks are gold and green.

Comment: @Richard, in which image are you referring?    Plus it's plausible the tubes are only filled while in the process of dispensing.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - [This one](http://www.technovelgy.com/graphics/content08/r2d2-serves-drinks-sail-barge.jpg)

Comment: @Richard:  Good image.

Comment: Yeah, I remembered him having a spigot, and possibly even using it.  That's why I asked.  :)